# Regex to get text After anchor tag C#

Tags: c#, regex, anchor

I have a C# Regex as follows:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<value1>.*?)<a.*?href=(""|')(?<href>.*?)(""|').*?>(?<value2>.*?)</a>(?<value3>.*?)");
```

I can get text for value1, href, value2 perfect. However, value3 is always "".

What am I missing to get the text that comes after the anchor closing tag().

Comment: you should not using a regex for parsing html.

Comment: To answer the question, I *believe* the `?` after the `.*` makes the expression non-greedy.  Maybe try removing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't return a null value if you would use a **Parser** instead, since parsing HTML with regular expression is not the best way to approach this. But to fix the issue, remove the non-greedy quantifier from the end of your expression making it greedy (*matching the most amount possible*).

```
(?<value3>.*?)
            ^ Remove non-greedy quantifier
```

And make it **greedy**:

```
(?<value3>.*)
```

See [**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/mT1rM9)